Is the space of multi-functional algebraic differential equation systems LARGER than the space of algebraic differential equations?
We first consider the space of functions that can be defined by an algebraic differential equations (let's call it AD for short).
That is a function $f$ is a member of AD if there exists a polynomial $P(A,B,C,...)$ with rational function coefficients s.t. $P(f,f',f'',f''',...) = 0$.
An example is $f = e^{x}$ and $P(A,B) = A - B$ so that $P(f,f') = f - f' = P(e^x, e^x) = 0$.
It's well known that this space AD is missing a lot of nice functions including the Gamma Function! This is known as Holder's Theorem.
It's natural to then ask "okay so I can't get the Gamma function by itself in a single polynomial diff eq, but is there a way to create a SYSTEM of diff Eqs that encode the gamma function?"
This is can we find another function $\Gamma_2$ and two polynomials $P,Q$ with rational function coefficients s.t.
$$ P(\Gamma, \Gamma', ... \Gamma^{(n)}, \Gamma_2, \Gamma_2', ... \Gamma_2^{(m)}) = 0 \\ Q(\Gamma, \Gamma', ... \Gamma^{(n)}, \Gamma_2, \Gamma_2', ... \Gamma_2^{(m)}) = 0 $$
(We refer to the class of functions as AD(2), with the original as AD(1)) And if thats not possible what about 2+ functions coupled together with the Gamma function (the general class being AD(3),AD(4),... AD(N), ... and the union of ALL classes as just ADT (
t for total
) ).
I want to believe that systems of 3+ algebraic differential equations cannot be simply reduced to a single algebraic differential equation. I believe that even for systems as simple as the Three body problem this leads to extremely complex and rich structure of the solution set, which would (I think) not have happened if the system can be re-written as JUST a single algebraic differential equation.
This brings me to my question:

Do we know for FACT that AD $\subset$  ADT?
If that is the case (and it likely is) then does there exist some $k$ such that $\Gamma \in AD(k)$?

I'm an optimist so I want to believe yes to both, but I lack the tools to know why or how.

Any n-th order ODE is equivalent to a first order system with the trivial substitution $y^{(n+1)}=(y^n)'$. So Hölders proof is for a system of n-1 linear first order equations plus one first order polynomial eqation. This is almost certainly a pointlike subset of general algebraic systems for any n.
